Rails ActionText Trix support for embedded attachments with expiring url? urls_expire_in
I tried using Trix in a project with ActiveStorage urls_expire_in 30 min option. After adding an embedded/inline image in Trix, a temporary url is saved in the body content (with a redirect and signature fragment valid for 30 minutes). Texts written in this way of course stop displaying images after this time. I wonder if Trix even supports the possibility of saving the image within the text body with url from rails_blob_url, which would be converted to a temporary URL each time the text is loaded from the database, or is this not the right way at all and should I use another storage without expiration time

the problem actually only occurs when both configuration options are set:
config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in = 30.minutes
config.active_storage.urls_expire_in = 30.minutes

After removing both, the default one is activated in ActiveStorage
ActiveStorage.service_urls_expire_in = app.config.active_storage.service_urls_expire_in || 5.minutes
and it works correctly. I'm closing this issue as for my use case using the service url is enough. It doesn't seem to work though, when urls_expire_in is set.
